# Error -206 table (aus_command) not in database

Tags: informix

Informix 11.70.TC4DE on Windows Vista SP2, i7 Dual Core, 8GB RAM:

I searched for (aus_command) table and it is in the database. Any idea why it says it could not find it?

```
Tue May 15 22:07:21 2012

22:07:21  Booting Language <c> from module <>
22:07:21  Loading Module <CNULL>
22:07:21  Booting Language <builtin> from module <>
22:07:21  Loading Module <BUILTINNULL>
22:07:28  DR: DRAUTO is 0 (Off)
22:07:28  DR: ENCRYPT_HDR is 0 (HDR encryption Disabled)
22:07:28  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.TC4DE Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
22:07:29  Performance Advisory: The physical log size is smaller than the recommended size for a
server configured with RTO_SERVER_RESTART.
22:07:29   Results: Fast recovery performance might not be optimal.
22:07:29   Action: For best fast recovery performance when RTO_SERVER_RESTART is enabled,
increase the physical log size to at least 242000 KB. For servers
configured with a large buffer pool, this might not be necessary. 
22:07:29  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Initialized -- Shared Memory Initialized.

22:07:29  Started 1 B-tree scanners.
22:07:29  B-tree scanner threshold set at 5000.
22:07:29  B-tree scanner range scan size set to -1.
22:07:29  B-tree scanner ALICE mode set to 6.
22:07:29  B-tree scanner index compression level set to med.
22:07:29  Physical Recovery Started at Page (2:5459).
22:07:29  Physical Recovery Complete: 0 Pages Examined, 0 Pages Restored.
22:07:29  Logical Recovery Started.
22:07:29  5 recovery worker threads will be started.
22:07:30  Logical Recovery has reached the transaction cleanup phase.
22:07:30  Logical Recovery Complete.
      6 Committed, 0 Rolled Back, 0 Open, 0 Bad Locks

22:07:31  Onconfig parameter STORAGE_FULL_ALARM modified from 0 to 3.
22:07:31  Dataskip is now OFF for all dbspaces
22:07:31  Init operation complete - Mode Online
22:07:31  Checkpoint Completed:  duration was 0 seconds.
22:07:31  Tue May 15 - loguniq 21, logpos 0x500b4, timestamp: 0xa252b Interval: 62

22:07:31  Maximum server connections 0 
22:07:31  Checkpoint Statistics - Avg. Txn Block Time 0.000, # Txns blocked 0, Plog used 16, Llog used 1

22:07:31  On-Line Mode
22:07:34  SCHAPI: Started dbScheduler thread.
22:07:36  Defragmenter cleaner thread now running
22:07:36  Defragmenter cleaner thread cleaned:0 partitions
22:07:36  Booting Language <spl> from module <>
22:07:36  Loading Module <SPLNULL>
22:07:36  Auto Registration is synced
22:07:36  SCHAPI: Started 2 dbWorker threads.
22:07:38  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Refresh 33-4] Error -206 The specified table (aus_command) is not in the database.

22:07:38  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Refresh 33-4] Error -111 ISAM error:  no record found.

22:07:38  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Refresh 33-4] Error -206 The specified table (aus_command) is not in the database.

22:07:38  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Refresh 33-4] Error -111 ISAM error:  no record found.

22:07:40  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Evaluation 32-8] Error -242 Could not open database table (informix.aus_command).

22:07:40  SCHAPI: [Auto Update Statistics Evaluation 32-8] Error -106 ISAM error:  non-exclusive access.

22:07:45  Logical Log 21 Complete, timestamp: 0xae6d3.
22:23:40  Explain file for session 31 : C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\sqexpln\cost.out
22:24:07  Explain file for session 31 : C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\sqexpln\cost.out
22:24:24  Explain file for session 31 : C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\sqexpln\cost.out
22:27:10  Checkpoint Completed:  duration was 0 seconds.
22:27:10  Tue May 15 - loguniq 22, logpos 0x545018, timestamp: 0xb4f29 Interval: 63

22:27:10  Maximum server connections 1 
22:27:10  Checkpoint Statistics - Avg. Txn Block Time 0.000, # Txns blocked 0, Plog used 657, Llog used 3573

22:27:11  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Stopped.
```

Comment: Which database did you look in?  The `sysadmin` database?

Comment: I'm not sure what's gone wrong.  Have you restarted IDS since these errors?  If not, try it. If you have and the errors are still occurring, then retrieve anything you added to the `sysadmin` database (any tasks you created, etc), then (as `informix`) drop the database and either restart IDS or run `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/bldadmin.sh` or its equivalent on Windows.

Comment: ended up unloading the tables, saved the procs, re-installed IDS and recreated the db.. the problem went away, however i've noticed that the Windows IDS version behaves strange at times with spurious problems!.. perhaps an onconfig or windows param needs to be tweaked?